# How to make Kendo notification work via angularjs service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have define the kendo notification in angular service but this following line is throwing an error uiService.notify.error("You missed some required fields.");
The error is Cannot read property 'show' of null
 how can I make it work ?

**HTML**

```
 <span kendo-notification="notification" k-options="notifyOptions"></span>
<button class="k-button" ng-click="showInContainer()">Show in container</button>
```

**controller.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('dataController', DataCtlr);

    DataCtlr.$inject = ['$scope', '$log', '$http', 'DataService','uiService'];

    function DataCtlr($scope, $log, $http, DataService, uiService) {
 $scope.showInContainer = function () {
        uiService.notify.error("You missed some required fields.");
    };
}
```

**service.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    app.factory("uiService", uiService);
    uiService.$inject = ["$rootScope", "$window", "$document"];

    function uiService($rootScope, $window, $document) {
        var svc = {
            settings: {},            
            notification: null, // kendo notification control
            notify: null
        };
        init();

        return svc;

        function init() {         
            initNotifications();

            $rootScope.ui = svc; // make available to the views
            $rootScope.notify = svc.notify; // for httpExceptionInterceptor
        }



        function initNotifications() {
            svc.notifyOptions = {
                templates: [{
                    type: "success",
                    template: "<div class='bg-success'><i class='fa fa-check' />#= message #</div>"
                }, {
                    type: "error",
                    template: "<div class='bg-danger'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-circle' />#= message #</div>"
                }, {
                    type: "info",
                    template: "<div class='bg-info'><i class='fa fa-info-circle' />#= message #</div>"
                }]
            }
            svc.notify = {
                success: function (message) {
                    svc.notification.show({ message: message }, 'success');
                },
                error: function (message) {
                    svc.notification.show({ message: message }, 'error');
                },
                info: function (message) {
                    svc.notification.show({ message: message }, 'info');
                }
            }
        }




    }
}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initialized my notification widget in my NotificationService and appended it to the body with jQuery. So i can ensure there is always only one instance of the widget because Kendos Doc says:

```
Using several Notification widget instances, which display notifications at
the same place on the page, is not recommended because the notifications from 
the multiple instances will overlap.
```

(compare http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/layout/notification/overview)

As I found out, there are also some issues if your properties of the widget - in your case notifyOptions e.g. - are undefined during widget initialization. Then your widget will fail silently.

So I prefer to init the notification widget in the service with the id of an html element. is it given, then it takes the reference to the HTML Element, otherwise it creates a default one.

in your service init (its typescript, but for javascript just remove the types):

```
// init dom element 
var temp = $("#" + notificationElementId);
var domElement: Element;
if (temp.length > 0) {
    domElement = temp[0];
} else {
    $("body").append('<span id="' + notificationElementId + '"></span>');
    domElement = $("#" + notificationElementId)[0];
}

// create notification widget (so you have the reference in your service)
this.notification = new kendo.ui.Notification(domElement, this.notificationOptions);
```

Other problem is of course, that you bind to notification property in controller scope, but have the variable in your service. So you need to assign it to    svc.notification as @dimodi said before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the Notification widget instance to `svc.notification`. You can try doing that inside or after `initNotifications()`, or by using a `kendoWidgetCreated` handler.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/global-events